# How to use laravel MustVerifyEmail (email verification) on a custom model

Tags: php, laravel, email-validation, email-verification, mail-sender

Ok so i have a model named `SiteEmail`. Basically i have a model named Site and it can have multiple emails associated with it, which has to be verified by sending an email. I want to use the laravel email verification that ships with laravel which i have used on the user model. I have implemented the `MustVerifyEmail` interface on the `SiteEmail` model and it is using the `Notifiable` trait. The emails are being sent fine, but on clicking on the verify button, it says invalid signature.

```
class SiteEmail extends Model implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use Notifiable;
    protected $fillable = ['site_id', 'user_id', 'email', 'email_verified_at'];

    /**
     * Determine if the user has verified their email address.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function hasVerifiedEmail()
    {
        return $this->email_verified_at != null;
    }

    /**
     * Mark the given user's email as verified.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function markEmailAsVerified()
    {
        $this->update([
            'email_verified_at' => now(),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Send the email verification notification.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function sendEmailVerificationNotification()
    {
        $this->notify(new VerifyEmail);
    }

    /**
     * Get the email address that should be used for verification.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmailForVerification()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }
}
```

How do i approach email verification on such models? It works fine on the `User` model, but i don't think this is the correct way to verify custom models. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

PS: I think this might be happening because the signature generated is being tested against the user's email?

Comment: Pull the contract it should work see; https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/contracts
MustVerifyEmail is pulled by Authenticable class.

Similar ;https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/mustverifyemail-it-is-not-a-trait

Comment: @DanysChalifour Nop still says invalid signature

Comment: 1. Is APP_URL the same you have domain or location of root directory? Pl do set like that.
2. Is forceHTTP enabled? Pl disable
3. `php artisan config:cache`


Hope these helps

Comment: @KaushikThakkar yes it is

Comment: Did it help or still stuck?

Comment: @KaushikThakkar no actually i didnot use the trait or the contract, ended up making something of my own. I think the default verify controller checks the email against the user's email or something like that. So i ended up creating a different route to verify the url instead of the default verify route, and verified the url's signature on a custom controller. But i still dont fell like i completely understand why is it happening.